# In React AuthContext Doesn't rerender when i change the state

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I created a use useState ( [logined,setLogined] ) in authContext and shared as a value, if even i change the logined value in signout my Navbar is not rerenderd why ?.  I placed useEffect in Navbar to Check when my logined state to print message in console. but it doesn't show anything.

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

let authContext = createContext();

let SERVER_URI = "http://localhost:3000";

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [logined, setLogined] = useState(false);
  
  useState(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${SERVER_URI}/login-status`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === "isLogined") setLogined(true);
      });
  }, []);

  let toggleLogined = () => {
    setLogined(!logined);
  };
  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={{ logined, setLogined, toggleLogined }}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default authContext;
export { AuthProvider };
```

> Navbar.js

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import authContext from "../context/authContext";

export default function Navbar() {
  let { logined, setLogined } = useContext(authContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Login state: ", logined);
  }, [logined]);

  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="flex p-5 bg-blue-500  mb-10 justify-between items-center">
        <h1 className="ml-5 text-2xl font-medium" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
          {logined ? "Logined" : "NotLogined"}
        </h1>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

> Signout.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import authContext from "../context/authContext";

let SERVER_URI = "http://localhost:3000";

export default function Signout() {
  let { setLogined, toggleLogined } = useContext(authContext);
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${SERVER_URI}/auth/signout`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        // setLogined(false);
        toggleLogined();
        navigate("/signin");
      });
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: you should use `useEffect`, not `useState` in `AuthProvider` for `axios` call

Comment: Ohh Sorry, Even Chat Gpt can't Find That Mistake. Thanks

Comment: But even after the change it doesn't works, same situation

Comment: are you sure that `${SERVER_URI}/login-status` call is successful, what is in the network? I believe problem is not in the React context,  but in this code:

```
axios
      .get(`${SERVER_URI}/login-status`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === "isLogined") setLogined(true);
      });
```

Comment: also (it is not relevant, but still) it's better to use `setLogined(prevLogined => !prevLogined)`

Comment: Thanks for helping, i just figured out, the problem is from backend, i just destroy the session and did not sent any response so that it failes to execute then block of fetch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using useState instead of useEffect in the context provider.Please try the below code.

```
    import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
        
        let authContext = createContext();
        
        let SERVER_URI = "http://localhost:3000";
        
        function AuthProvider({ children }) {
          const [logined, setLogined] = useState(false);
          
          useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async function(){
              axios
              .get(`${SERVER_URI}/login-status`, {
                withCredentials: true,
              })
              .then((res) => {
                if (res.data.status === "isLogined") setLogined(true);
              });
              }
               fetchData()
          }, []);
        
          let toggleLogined = () => {
            setLogined(!logined);
          };
          return (
            <authContext.Provider value={{ logined, setLogined, toggleLogined }}>
              {children}
            </authContext.Provider>
          );
        }
        
        export default authContext;
        export { AuthProvider };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).